# Kernel Won't start in Jupyter notebook in python 3 version

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, anaconda3, jupyter-kernel

Recently I install the latest version of anaconda with python 3 version on my mac OS Catalina. When I am opening the jupyter notebook, the kernel is not starting. I am getting the following error on the terminal;

The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 22:46:39.629 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/
[I 22:46:39.629 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).

[I 22:47:35.290 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in
[I 22:47:37.697 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 4117cc19-e88c-4ce6-8d07-667be4334b90
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in 
from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/**init**.py", line 2, in 
from .connect import *
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 8, in 
import json
File "/Users/shubhamsharma/json.py", line 35
print data_to_MLab(csv_file)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[I 22:47:40.694 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in 
from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/**init**.py", line 2, in 
from .connect import *
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 8, in 
import json
File "/Users/shubhamsharma/json.py", line 35
print data_to_MLab(csv_file)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[I 22:47:43.706 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (2/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in 
from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/**init**.py", line 2, in 
from .connect import *
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 8, in 
import json
File "/Users/shubhamsharma/json.py", line 35
print data_to_MLab(csv_file)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[I 22:47:46.717 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (3/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in 
from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/**init**.py", line 2, in 
from .connect import *
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 8, in 
import json
File "/Users/shubhamsharma/json.py", line 35
print data_to_MLab(csv_file)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[I 22:47:49.726 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in 
from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/**init**.py", line 2, in 
from .connect import *
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 8, in 
import json
File "/Users/shubhamsharma/json.py", line 35
print data_to_MLab(csv_file)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[W 22:47:52.735 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 22:47:52.736 NotebookApp] Kernel 4117cc19-e88c-4ce6-8d07-667be4334b90 died, removing from map.
[W 22:48:37.732 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 4117cc19-e88c-4ce6-8d07-667be4334b90
[E 22:48:37.735 NotebookApp] Error opening stream: HTTP 404: Not Found (Kernel does not exist: 4117cc19-e88c-4ce6-8d07-667be4334b90)
[W 22:48:39.487 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/4117cc19-e88c-4ce6-8d07-667be4334b90/channels?session_id=3c13c1ca972d45488619325622a32bfb (::1): Kernel does not exist: 4117cc19-e88c-4ce6-8d07-667be4334b90
[W 22:48:39.497 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/4117cc19-e88c-4ce6-8d07-667be4334b90/channels?session_id=3c13c1ca972d45488619325622a32bfb (::1) 13.92ms referer=None
[W 22:48:41.621 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: 4117cc19-e88c-4ce6-8d07-667be4334b90:3c13c1ca972d45488619325622a32bfb
[I 22:49:37.633 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Untitled58.ipynb
[W 22:52:46.606 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: 4117cc19-e88c-4ce6-8d07-667be4334b90:3c13c1ca972d45488619325622a32bfb

Exactly, I don't know what happened by I tried all the possible solutions but It does not work. I reinstall again and again nut it does not work. The kernel is not starting after several attempts.

Plz, help me with this issue. I am very grateful if you can solve this issue